# Rename a Perspective in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, perspective

Is there a way to Rename the Perspective in Eclipse? I want to open multiple instances of eclipse for the same project & this will help me since i can know exactly which one I am using by looking at the taskbar.

Answer (score 3):

You can create your own perspectives though and give it a name that suits you. You should have a 'Save Perspective As' button in you main menu, it is in the 'Window' submenu by default i think. Hope that helps.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think that there is a way to do this, perspective is kind of different view that suites what you are doing now in eclipse (coding, debug, svn, ...). You can customize Perspective as you want from Window->Customize Perspective, but giving it a name, I don't think that there is a way to do that. If you want to take this further than that, you can check this [here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_create_a_new_perspective?) to see how to create a new perspective programmatically.